# Cartopy fails to correctly contour data on rotated grid

Tags: cartopy

when contouring a dataset that is defined on a rotated pole grid, I get the following result:

[image]

This is only a problem when using `contour` and `contourf`, not `pcolormesh`.

Anyone have any idea what could be going on here? Should I file a bug report, and if yes, should I do so with cartopy or with matplotlib?

**Reproducing**

- example notebook https://github.com/lvankampenhout/stackoverflow-rotatedpole/blob/master/Minimum%20example.ipynb
- example data http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~kampe004/files/snow_rlat_rlon.nc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data for contouring should be split into 2 parts to avoid errors you found. I choose `longitude=0` as the dividing line. Numpy's masked array technique is used to achieve the data manipulation. Here is the working code that produces a useful plot.

```
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.ma as ma
from netCDF4 import Dataset

nc = Dataset('./data/snow_rlat_rlon.nc')

# Prep values for contouring
snow_2d_array = nc.variables[u'snowfall'][:]   # need *(86400*365); mm/s-> mm/yr
lat_2d_array = nc.variables[u'lat2d'][:]
lon_2d_array = nc.variables[u'lon2d'][:]

# do masked-array on the lon_2d
lon2d_greater = ma.masked_greater(lon_2d_array, -0.01)
lon2d_lesser = ma.masked_less(lon_2d_array, 0)

# apply masks to other associate arrays: lat_2d
lat2d_greater = ma.MaskedArray(lat_2d_array, mask=lon2d_greater.mask)
lat2d_lesser = ma.MaskedArray(lat_2d_array, mask=lon2d_lesser.mask)
# apply masks to other associate arrays: snow_2d
snow_2d_greater = ma.MaskedArray(snow_2d_array, mask=lon2d_greater.mask)
snow_2d_lesser = ma.MaskedArray(snow_2d_array, mask=lon2d_lesser.mask)

# set levels for contouring of snow_2d
levels = (0, 25, 50, 75, 100, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000, 2000, 4000)

# get snow_2d value-limits for use with colormap
vmax, vmin = snow_2d_array.max()*86400*365, snow_2d_array.min()*86400*365
cmap1 = "viridis"
norm1 = colors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries=levels, ncolors=16)
norm2 = colors.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax/4)

# setup fig+axes, specifying projection to use
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.SouthPolarStereo()})
fig.set_size_inches([10, 10])

ax.coastlines(color="red", linewidth=2)  # draw coastlines in red

# plot contour using each part of the 2 masked data sets
ct1 = ax.contour(lon2d_greater, lat2d_greater, snow_2d_greater*86400*365, \
                 norm=norm2, levels=levels, \
                 transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ct2 = ax.contour(lon2d_lesser, lat2d_lesser, snow_2d_lesser*86400*365, \
                 norm=norm2, levels=levels, \
                 transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()) 

#plt.colorbar(ct1, shrink=0.85)
plt.show()
```

The output plot:

[image: spole_plot]

For filled-contour, replace `ax.contour()` with `ax.contourf()` and add:

```
ax.set_xlim((-4052327.4304452268, 4024164.250636036))
```

in front of `plt.show()`.

[image: contourf]

Hope it is useful to your project.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this workaround! Hadn't thought of that. However, IMHO this still doesn't fully answer the question whether the default behaviour (giving the ugly plot) should be considered a bug or not. Could you comment on that?

Comment: @LeovanKampenhout : I would consider it a bug on Cartopy side. If you look at `cartopy` source code, https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.5/_modules/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.html, for `geoaxes` class (subclassing from matplotlib's axes, a cartesian system), its methods `contour()` and `contourf()` have additional coordinate transformation process only. No specific treatment of geospatial coordinates requirements.